# How do I make this typescript mapping function much less complex?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, node-serialport

I'm trying to do a pretty simple map between some known values to some other known values. Everything about this code screams I'm missing something simple that typescript can do.

```
type PortInfoProp = 'comName' | 'manufacturer' | 'serialNumber' | 'vendorId' | 'productId' | 'pnpId'

interface LinuxPort extends PortInfo {}

interface PropNames {
  readonly DEVLINKS: PortInfoProp
  readonly DEVNAME: PortInfoProp
  readonly ID_MODEL_ID: PortInfoProp
  readonly ID_SERIAL_SHORT: PortInfoProp
  readonly ID_VENDOR_ENC: PortInfoProp
  readonly ID_VENDOR_ID: PortInfoProp
}

type PropName = keyof PropNames

function propName(name: PropName): PortInfoProp | null {
  const map: PropNames = {
    DEVNAME: 'comName',
    ID_VENDOR_ENC: 'manufacturer',
    ID_SERIAL_SHORT: 'serialNumber',
    ID_VENDOR_ID: 'vendorId',
    ID_MODEL_ID: 'productId',
    DEVLINKS: 'pnpId',
  }
  return map[name] || null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd do is move your map outside of the function; there's no need to recreate it on each call. You can then declare your mapping as a dictionary:

```
type PropName = 'DEVNAME' | 'ID_VENDOR_ENC' | 'ID_SERIAL_SHORT' | 'ID_VENDOR_ID' | 'ID_MODEL_ID' | 'DEVLINKS';
type PortInfoProp = 'comName' | 'manufacturer' | 'serialNumber' | 'vendorId' | 'productId' | 'pnpId';

type PropertyMapping = { [key in PropName]: PortInfoProp };

const map: PropertyMapping = {
  DEVNAME: 'comName',
  ID_VENDOR_ENC: 'manufacturer',
  ID_SERIAL_SHORT: 'serialNumber',
  ID_VENDOR_ID: 'vendorId',
  ID_MODEL_ID: 'productId',
  DEVLINKS: 'pnpId',
}

function propName(name: PropName): PortInfoProp | null {
  return map[name] || null
}
```

**Edit**:

More succinct if you don't care to have named types for your map keys/values:

```
const map = {
  DEVNAME: 'comName',
  ID_VENDOR_ENC: 'manufacturer',
  ID_SERIAL_SHORT: 'serialNumber',
  ID_VENDOR_ID: 'vendorId',
  ID_MODEL_ID: 'productId',
  DEVLINKS: 'pnpId',
}

type PropMapping = typeof map;

function propName<K extends keyof PropMapping>(name: K): PropMapping[K] | null {
  return map[name] || null
}
```

Comment: Of course, given `map` as in the second variant, it's possible to define named types `type PropName = keyof PropMapping` and `type PortInfoProp = PropMapping[PropName]`.

Comment: Also in the second variant, you could get your string literal types back if you do something like `const lit = <K extends string | number | boolean>(k: K) => k;` and then `{ DEVNAME: lit('comName'), ID_VENDOR_ENC: lit('manufacturer') ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement was a bit more concise.

```
type PortInfoProp = 'comName' | 'manufacturer' | 'serialNumber' | 'vendorId' | 'productId' | 'pnpId'
type PropName = 'DEVLINKS' | 'DEVNAME' | 'ID_MODEL_ID' | 'ID_SERIAL_SHORT' | 'ID_VENDOR_ENC' | 'ID_VENDOR_ID'

function propName(name: PropName): PortInfoProp | null {
  switch (name) {
    case 'DEVNAME':
      return 'comName'
    case 'ID_VENDOR_ENC':
      return 'manufacturer'
    case 'ID_SERIAL_SHORT':
      return 'serialNumber'
    case 'ID_VENDOR_ID':
      return 'vendorId'
    case 'ID_MODEL_ID':
      return 'productId'
    case 'DEVLINKS':
      return 'pnpId'
    default:
      return null
  }
}
```